# ThreadSafe Dictionary... Key Value Pairs Enumerable? (.net)

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm perusing (considering writing my own thread safe dictionary) I found the following implementation.

http://devplanet.com/blogs/brianr/archive/2008/09/26/thread-safe-dictionary-in-net.aspx

It looks pretty good generally, but there's one thing that confuses me.

The following:
Cannot enumerate a threadsafe dictionary.  Instead, enumerate the keys or values collection

which is found in both the

```
public virtual IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetEnumerator()
{
    throw new NotSupportedException("Cannot enumerate a threadsafe dictionary.  Instead, enumerate the keys or values collection");
}


IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
    throw new NotSupportedException("Cannot enumerate a threadsafe dictionary.  Instead, enumerate the keys or values collection");
}
```

What I don't get is why it's ok to enumerate the keys or values, but not the kvp's of the dictionary?

Could someone shed some light on this for me?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

SO user and MS employee [JaredPar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23283/jaredpar) has a short series on his blog about building threadsafe collections that's definitely worth your time:

- [Why are thread safe collections so hard?](http://blogs.msdn.com/jaredpar/archive/2009/02/11/why-are-thread-safe-collections-so-hard.aspx)
- [A more usable API for a mutable thread safe collection](http://blogs.msdn.com/jaredpar/archive/2009/02/16/a-more-usable-thread-safe-collection.aspx)

**[Update:]**
Reading through them again, if you're short of time the 2nd article can probably stand on it's own.

To summarize: most "threadsafe" collections you find posted online are generally either not very useful or only thread safe one operation at a time, making "decision" members like `.Count` or `.Contains` useless (they're "stale" by the time the next line of code runs).

Answer (score 2):

I can answer that question directly, since I wrote that dictionary :)

Obtaining an enumerator on the dictionary will get a reference to the internal KVP sets.  You would have to hold the read lock until you are done enumerating, which could be a long while.

The reason I say to enumerate the keys or values instead, is that I **copy** the list of keys and values when it is requested, therefore I am not returning a reference to the dictionaries internal list, which if you altered out of lock, could cause issues.  Although, I suppose you could implement the same pattern on the KVP's as well if you wanted since they are read only.

```
    public virtual ICollection<TKey> Keys
    {
        get
        {
            using (new ReadOnlyLock(this.dictionaryLock))
            {
                return new List<TKey>(this.dict.Keys);
            }
        }
    }

    public virtual ICollection<TValue> Values
    {
        get
        {
            using (new ReadOnlyLock(this.dictionaryLock))
            {
                return new List<TValue>(this.dict.Values);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Couldn't you copy the internal list as well?

Comment: the real trick to that is that you still couldn't use the enumerator, as it is stateful.  If 2 threads attempted to enumerate at the same time, where would you store the copied list?

Comment: I was thinking more like, Lock -> Copy array -> UnLock -> then return enumerator on copied version.

Comment: Not a bad plan. Though it does violate one of the implied properties of enumeration, in that the list you are enumerating should not change during enumeration.  Either way, as long as that is understood, I guess it wouldn't hurt.

Comment: @BrianRudolph: Specifying that enumerators should always throw exceptions if collections are modified was IMHO a mistake; a better spec would have been to specify what behaviors should be acceptable or unacceptable if an enumerator doesn't throw, and specify that enumerators that can't guarantee acceptable behavior if a collection is modified should throw an exception rather than doing something unacceptable.  With many types of collections, throwing an exception would be easier than e.g. ensuring that every item which exists throughout an enumeration gets returned exactly once, but...

Comment: ...if a collection can uphold the expected enumerable contract without throwing an exception, such behavior should be considered desirable.  An enumerator which returns a snapshot of the collection as of the moment it was created should generally be regarded as upholding any reasonable enumeration contract.

Answer (score 1):

When you enumerate over the collection of KVP you are dipping into and out of the lock for the entire dictionary. So in the loop body of your enumeration you are not in the lock, and changing the KVP could cause a race condition.